# How to adjust Do loop with conditions?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, do

This code works as expected.

```
ClearAll[cap,othA,h,dim,Ast,br,nbr];

cap = {400, 600, 700, 500, 300, 900};
othA = {200, 350, 100, 200, 450, 250};
h = {{0, 20, 0, 5, 20, 0},
   {10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 40},
   {10, 15, 0, 5, 0, 0},
   {8, 5, 0, 0, 35, 0},
   {0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 35},
   {10, 0, 10, 0, 25, 0}};
dim = Length[cap];
Ast = Table[othA[[i]] + Total@h[[i]], {i, dim}]
br = {1, 3, 5}; (*bankrupts*)
nbr = Complement[Range[dim], br]; (*excluding bankrupts*)

\[Lambda] = 0.5;

z = 0;
While[cap[[i]] > 0,
 {
  Do[
   If[
    cap[[i]] > 0,
    {
     cap[[i]] = cap[[i]] - \[Lambda]*Sum[h[[i, j]], {j, br}],
     Ast[[i]] = 
      othA[[i]] + 
       Sum[h[[i, j]], {j, nbr}] + (1 - \[Lambda])*
        Sum[h[[i, j]], {j, br}]
     }
    ], {i, dim}
   ]
  };
 z++
 ]

{cap, Ast, z}
```

This generates:

```
{{0., 200., 500., -16., 200., 0.}, {235., 400., 125., 226.5, 497.5, 
  272.5}, 40}
```

I want to run the same code again using an updated matrix `h` by deleting those rows and columns that are associated with the negative elements in the first list of the output.

Namely, the 4th element `-16` in {0., 200., 500., **-16.,** 200., 0.} means that I need to drop from matrix `h` the 4-th row and column, then proceed with the same calculations in DO loop by using the updated matrix `h`.

Comment: `pos =Position[list, item_/;item<0]` will find the positions, then you can use `h=Delete[h,pos]` The documentation will have examples

Comment: @Craig Carter: I can find the position of negative elements and delete the relevant row and columns. But I cannot integrate that information into the DO loop to repetitively carry out the operations until no element is negative.

Comment: `! AllTrue[h // Flatten, NonNegative]` will be `True` if `h` contains a negative value